# Disable uitableview disable reuse when scrolling in iOS

Tags: swift, ios7

I want to disable reloading table view when scrolling. Now, my app when user scroll the uitableview, cellForRowAtIndexPath has been recalled.

**Things in viewDidLoad**

```
[listingTableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"TripCardCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:[TripCardCell cellID]];
```

**Things in cellForRowAtIndexPath**

```
if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[TripCardCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:[TripCardCell cellID]];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }
```

Comment: does that work for your trouble

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **UITableViewCell Class Reference**
>
> The reuse identifier is associated with a UITableViewCell object that
>   the table-view’s delegate creates with the intent to reuse it as the
>   basis (for performance reasons) for multiple rows of a table view. It
>   is assigned to the cell object in initWithFrame:reuseIdentifier: and
>   cannot be changed thereafter. A UITableView object maintains a queue
>   (or list) of the currently reusable cells, each with its own reuse
>   identifier, and makes them available to the delegate in the
>   dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: method.

**Advantage of reuseIdentifiers**

> Using dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier for the tableView, you can
>   greatly speed things up. Instead of instantiating a lot of cells, you
>   just instantiate as many as needed, i.e. as many that are visible
>   (this is handled automatically). If scrolling to an area in the list
>   where there are "cells" that haven't got their visual representation
>   yet, instead of instantiating new ones, you reuse already existing
>   ones.

**disable reloading tableview when scrolling**

> You cannot block the cellForRowAtIndexPath: from calling when
>   scrolling the tableview. If something need not happen every time, You
>   may keep it in if condition.

```
 if (cell == nil)
    {
        //Functionality goes here when it not needed to happen every time.
    }
```